# Cannot run an executable file although it's right there

Tags: files, executable

I'm completely new to the Unix environment. I've only switched to Ubuntu recently because the program I need doesn't work on the OS that I'm using.

Like the title says: install* won't run. It says `no such file or directory`, but I know that it is there.

```
welcome@welcome:~/Downloads/quartus_free$ ls
adm.gz     compare      cyc4gx_we.gz  devinfo_we.gz   gtar     ip.gz         linux.gz    m7k_we.gz     perlsrc.gz   readme.txt   space.txt   stx4_we.gz    version.txt
agx_we.gz  cusp.gz      cycii_we.gz   dsp_builder.gz  gzip     ip_lic.txt    lmf.gz      manifest.txt  qcleanup     sgxii_we.gz  stub.csh    stx_we.gz     
aii_we.gz  cyc3_we.gz   cyc_we.gz     eda.gz          help.gz  libraries.gz  m3k_we.gz   maxii_we.gz   qdesigns.gz  sgx_we.gz    stx2_we.gz  sys_reqs.txt  
common.gz  cyc4e_we.gz  dev_info.txt  gpl_lic.txt     install  license.txt   m7ka_we.gz  md5sum.txt    qt           sopc.g       stx3_we.gz  tutorial.gz   
welcome@welcome:~/Downloads/quartus_free$ ./install
bash: ./install: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
welcome@welcome:~/Downloads/quartus_free$
```

Comment: Also, next time, copy-paste the output instead of taking a screenshot like this: `bash: ./install: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: @EvanChen I just finished transcribing the text from the image to text form in the question. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: @EvanChen tks for the tip. I'll make sure to do it next time.

Comment: @OwenHines tks for doing it for me this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message could be translated like this:

> Hey, I am `bash`. You ran `./install` and this script says I should run it with the interpreter `/bin/csh`. I can't find this program, though.

So the install script was made for the shell `csh` and it is not installed on your system.
This is how you can solve that:

```
sudo apt install csh
```

When the installation of `csh` is done, run `./install` again.

Answer (score 6):

It's not complaining about the *file* not being there, it's complaining about the C shell *interpreter* not being available on your system: you need to install one of the available `csh` implementations - for example, either

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

for the TENEX C Shell ("an enhanced version of Berkeley csh") or

```
sudo apt-get install csh
```

for a re-implementation of the original BSD C shell.

Answer (score 1):

What the error is saying is that the shell (`csh`) used to run the executable isn't installed. You can install `csh` using

```
sudo apt-get install csh
```

Answer (score 0):

The error text says ".. /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory".

This means that 'install' want's to be executed by '/bin/csh' (has a '#!/bin/csh' in first line), but csh isn't installed.

Run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install csh
```

and then rerun `./install`